# Executing loop values one after another in xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, nsmutablearray

By adding this code in `viewDidLoad` :

```
NSMutableArray   *array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:
                               @"Hefeweizen", @"IPA", @"Pilsner", @"Stout", nil];

    NSLog(@"array %@",array);
```

This is the `NSLog` I get :

```
array (
    Hefeweizen,
    IPA,
    Pilsner,
    Stout
)
```

How to get values one by one instead of showing total value in `NSLog` for example:

```
array{hefeweizen} 
array{IPA}
array{Pilsner}
array{Stout}
```

Comment: `for (NSString *aString in array){}`? Or do you want to overwrite `description`?

Comment: I'm trying to show the all values in label in viewDidLoad by loading one by one. Now what I get is "Stout" since its the last value. I want all the all values executed in label one after another(kind of loop).

Comment: yes [array objectAtIndex:0]

Comment: @ArunKumar By mentioning specific index in show the exact value in label. But I want to show all value showing up in label one by one once it is executed.

Comment: could you prescribe your need in a brief ?? could you want should contain dict with array ? means  a key with a value ?

Comment: no! Simple I have a label. I placed the above array in viewdidload. When I run the code the 4th element gets displayed in label. What I want is like a merry go round once I run the app label sud display 1st element in array then 2nd second one again third one then final one.

Answer (score 0):

```
Ex 1: array[0],array[1]....;

Ex 2: [array objectAtIndex:0]..;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 //Initialise More data
    setMoreArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSMutableDictionary *setData = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];[setData setObject:@"profile.png" forKey:@"icon"];[setData setObject:@"inloyal Profile" forKey:@"lable"];[setMoreArray addObject:setData]; 

some thing like this   ??

op:

array ->

(

{
 "icon" = "profile.png"
},
{
 "lable" = "inloyal Profile"
}
)
```

Comment: kind of same without dictionary.

Comment: NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"now", nil],[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"now1", nil],[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"now2", nil], nil];  ??

Comment: this can return   (
       (
     
        new
        ),
     (
           
      new1
        ),
     (
              
            new2
            )
    )

Answer (score 0):

I tried this code and it worked correctly :

```
NSUInteger index;

int64_t delayInSeconds = 5.0;

NSMutableArray   *array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:
                           @"Hefeweizen", @"IPA", @"Pilsner", @"Stout", nil];

NSMutableArray   *arrayac = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];



index = 0;

for ( id item in array )
{




    dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC);

    dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){



        [arrayac insertObject:item atIndex:index];
        NSLog(@"dest array %@   ",arrayac);
        NSLog(@"last object in the array %@   ",[arrayac lastObject]);

        testLabel.text = [arrayac lastObject];


    }); 


    delayInSeconds += 1;

    index++;




}
```

I placed this code in viewDidLoad and after running the code, exactly after 5sec delay the label changed one after another in a interval of 1sec. I wanted is to show the all values in the array showing up one by one.